# How do I automatically link foreign key id in html

Tags: html, django

I created my models in `django` below:

**Models**

```
class TermPolicyPeriod(models.Model):
    term = models.IntegerField()
    start_term = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    end_term = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    term_end = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class TermPolicyDetails(models.Model):
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    class_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    week_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    students_per_coach = models.IntegerField()
    start_class_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    end_class_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    duration_class_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=350, null=True)
    foreign_key_term_end = models.ForeignKey(TermPolicyPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views**

```
...
args = {
        # Term Policies - Period
        'new_term_policy_period_form': new_term_policy_period_form,
        'term_period_policy_page_data': term_period_policy_page_data,
        'edited_tpp': edited_tpp,
        # Term Policies - Details
        'new_term_policy_details_form': new_term_policy_details_form,
        'term_policy_details_page_data': term_policy_details_page_data,
        'edited_tpd': edited_tpd,
    }
    return render(request, 'static/html/home.html', args)
```

Within the forms that I want to create in `html`, I would like for the `foreign key` to be linked automatically to the `TermPolicyPeriod pk`. I've been searching around, but i'm unsure how the `syntax` should be written. I've thought of something along the lines of

```
<form> 
{% csrf_token %}
{% for pp in new_term_policy_period_form %}
    {% for pd in new_term_policy_details_form %}
        {% set pd.foreign_key_term_end_id = pp.pk %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

...
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Is something like this possible in html?

Answer (score 0):

In order to set foreign key properly you should create new `TermPolicyPeriod` instance within `form.is_valid()` in your views and then set foreign key of `TermPolicyDetails` to pk of that instance.